# Get name of image on click of image in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

(Using VB.NET but if can find solution in c#, then also i can convert it in VB.NET)

I have datalist containing several images and labels containing name of images.

I wanted to get the label's text(i.e. name of image) on clicking of particular image.

My data list:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" Height="200px" Width="200px"  runat="server" CommandName="imgClick"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PageName") %>'      />
               <asp:Label ID="lblImageName" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("PageName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

.cs code for binding datasource:

```
Protected Sub dlImages_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles dlImages.ItemDataBound
            If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.EditItem Then
                CType(e.Item.FindControl("ImageButton1"), ImageButton).ImageUrl = "~/ScreenMasterImages/" & e.Item.DataItem("PageName") & ".jpg"
            End If
        End Sub
```

For getting the value of label's text in datalist, upon clicking of image within datalist, i have tried following:

```
Protected Sub dlImages_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dlImages.ItemCommand
            If e.CommandName = "imgClick" Then
                imgURL = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblImageName"), Label).Text

                '((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblImgName")).Text;'
                'Response.Redirect("dailydealsdetail.aspx?imgurl=" + imgURL);
            End If
        End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this event is not getting fired, and i am not getting the name of image on click of imagebutton within datasource.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occuring because datalist was newly getting binded on each pageload.

I added if condition on pageload where i binded my datalist.

```
If Not Page.IsPostback Then

...Code for binding datalist.......

End IF
```